# iOS 10 How to view a list of pending notifications using UNUserNotificationCenter?

Tags: ios, swift3, ios10, unusernotificationcenter

Solution Code:

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
print(center.getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: { error in
        // error handling here
    }))
```

---

My original post:

I am trying to get a list of pending notifications via UNUserNotificationCenter as `UIApplication.shared.scheduledLocalNotifications` was depreciated.

This is the code I'm using:

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    print(UNUserNotificationCenter.getPendingNotificationRequests(center))
```

However this prints "(Function)". getPendingNotificationRequests requires a UNUserNotificationCenter parameter and I can't think of what else it could be.

Thanks

Comment: Call that function on `center`, not on the class and provide a callback handler https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649513-getpendingnotificationrequests

Comment: Can you mark my answer as accepted?

Comment: First make sure you've authorization, then you can schedule notification.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The `getPendingNotificationRequests` call passes an array of requests to the completion closure.  Try something like this:

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: { requests in
    for request in requests {
        print(request)
    }
})
```

Comment: It's always giving me 0 in ios 13.. I am using the device not emulator.. any idea about this ?

Comment: @Abhishek Are you sure they are being scheduled correctly? Do the notifications show properly?

Comment: Notifications are getting scheduled properly. But getting requests count as 0.

Comment: @Abhishek I'm having the same issue. Have you figured it out already?

Comment: How do you print the title? it just shows redacted for all of them

Comment: Make sure your app has requested the authorization to send notifications and you have accepted. That might be the reason for some of you to see 0.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case anyone needs to access notifications that are already delivered (user can see them in notification center), this can be done in the following way:

```
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.getDeliveredNotifications { notifications in
            // use center.removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers:requestIdsToRemove)
            // if you want to cancel some of the notifications displayed to user
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not actually now, but you should allow to use notifications

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
        if !granted {
            print("user has declined notifications")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

For ObjC:-
[[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] getPendingNotificationRequestsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray<UNNotificationRequest*> *requests){
NSLog(@"requests: %@", requests);
}];